# Default behavior of matplotlib imshow()

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

In matplotlib, when using `imshow()`, the default behavior is to display the image with bilinear interpolation.

I know I can change this explicitly by calling `imshow(...,interpolation='none')`. But this is cumbersome for many calls to `imshow`.

How do I change the default behavior, to e.g, `interpolation='none'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it!
Apparently, there's a dictionary controlling many aspects of matplotlib, called 
`rcParams`. Straight from [the matplotlib docs](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html#dynamic-rc-settings):

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['lines.linewidth'] = 2
mpl.rcParams['lines.color'] = 'r'
```

In my case, I had to set:

```
rcParams['image.interpolation']='none'
```